# How to deal with the non-uniqueness of SVD in numerical applications?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, svd

There are many applications in applied mathematics where the SVD of a matrix comes in handy. For example, consider the problem where we want to find an approximate solution to a(n) (overdetermined) linear system of equations $A\vec{x}=0$ subject to $\|\vec{x}\|=1$. It can be shown that the last column of $V$ in $A = UDV^t$ is the solution to this system subject to $\|\vec{x}\| = 1$.

The problem is that the SVD of a matrix is not unique. $U$ and $V$ are orthonormal matrices but we still have freedom in choosing signs. In cases like this, how can I do something that resolves the ambiguity? Is there a trick or a natural convention for the signs that ensures I always get the same answer no matter what?

In particular, what can I do in MATLAB to avoid this ambiguity?

**Edit:**

A specific example where non-uniquess can become an issue:

Suppose that you want to measure the intrinsic parameters of a [pinhole camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model). It turns out that in practical cases, $K$, the calibration matrix, 
is an upper triangular matrix. A little bit of algebraic manipulation, gives us a symmetric matrix $B=K^{-t}K^{-1}$ which has a nice interpretation and it's sufficient for finding $K$. Anyway, to find $K$, you will take photos of a checkerboard pattern and generally, you arrive at a linear system like $A_{n \times 6} \times b_{6 \times 1}=0_{n \times 1}$ with the additional constraint that $\|\vec{b}\|=1$ (to avoid the trivial answer). Here are some numerical results that I have obtained for $B$ after running the algorithm on synthesized checkerboard photos:

\begin{bmatrix}
   0.000000082076150  && -0.000000000008003 && -0.000037912894906 \\
  -0.000000000008003  &&  0.000000071823158  && -0.000055278469079 \\
  -0.000037912894906  && -0.000055278469079  && 0.999999997753446 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  -0.000000104164118  && -0.000000000027239  &&  0.000053428189068 \\
  -0.000000000027239  && -0.000000091142604  && 0.000067709246949 \\
   0.000053428189068  &&  0.000067709246949  && -0.999999996280434
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0.000000109630415  && 0.000000000051933  && -0.000056355404234 \\
   0.000000000051933  && 0.000000095949976  && -0.000071441815015 \\
  -0.000056355404234  && -0.000071441815015 &&  0.999999995860057
  \end{bmatrix}
Since $K$ is intrinsic and it only depends on the structure of the camera itself, the values we find for $p_x$, $p_y$, $f_x$ and $f_y$ must remain close to each other. Unfortunately, using the above matrices, sometimes $p_x$ and $p_y$ are minus their actual values. I blame the sign inconsistency of SVD decomposition for this.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to how non-uniqueness becomes a problem?

Comment: Enforce a positive determinant for $U$ and the ambiguity is gone.

Comment: Yep, my bad. You could enforce a particular element being positive, but this doesn't work when the element is zero. This is why I suggested a determinant.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit how your $A,U,D,V,x,K,b,p_x,p_y,f_x,f_y$ and your $3$ experimental matrices relate to each other?

Comment: @IlikeSerena the relations are nonlinear and boring. I'm afraid my post will get too long beyond reason if I write down all the relations in it. In short, the matrices I have written are the results obtained for $B=K^{-t}K^{-1}$. $K$ itself is an upper triangular matrix that has the form [$f_x$,$s$,$p_x$;0,$f_y$,$p_y$;0,0,1] in MATLAB notation. You can now compute $B$. In many applications, $s$ is assumed to be $0$ which simplifies the equations and makes things less non-linear.

Comment: @stressedout So to distill the problem you're running into: you would like to have it so that when the matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ are close to each other, you can guarantee that  the corresponding $U_1$ and $U_2$ computed will be close to each other.  Is that the gist?

Comment: Doesn't it suffice to pick the pixel scaling factors and focal length to be positive?

Comment: Do the negative $p_x,p_y$ form a solution that is equally valid to the solution you want? Perhaps your checkerboard pattern (being symmetric) is noise sensitive so that the solutions can swap independently of the SVD?

Comment: @stressedout How are you getting multiple measurements for the intrinsic parameters? As I recall, the procedure for measuring them consists of taking  several photos from different angles, putting all the keypoints in a matrix, then crunching numbers with the svd to solve a problem that produces a *single* set of measurements.  No matter how many pictures you took, they'd all go into the same single computation that is aimed toward a *single* set of parameters. Are you measuring multiple times and getting wildly different answers for some reason?

Comment: @rschwieb  I have already enforced $f_x$ and $f_y$ to be positive. Yet, I get $\pm5.140490e+02$ and $\pm7.445736e+02$. There are different ways to calibrate a matrix. I know 3 methods. One is to directly solve a linear system, which can't be applied here because my world frame is on the checkerboard and $z$ is always $0$ (hence it's impossible to recover the third column of $P$). The second method is to use homography transformations, the third one is to use vanishing points. Which method do you have in mind? Also, please remove some of your comments if possible.

Comment: @Raaja  overdetermined systems almost always are inconsistent. This is where the condition that $\|x\| = 1$ comes into play. $\| \cdot \|$ here denotes the Euclidean norm, but one can use other norms. It really depends on you to choose what you're looking for. This is what rschwieb refers to as a best-fit solution.

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry for my mistake, I completely agree with you.

Comment: @Raaja please remove your comments if possible. This section is getting too long. I'm also deleting my comments that I'm sure have been read.

Comment: @IlikeSerena  Yes, unfortunately negative values for $p_x$ and $p_y$ are equally valid. $p_x$ and $p_y$ are called the principal points of the camera's sensor. Consider a 2D frame where the origin is in $(2,2)$. It makes perfect sense if we have $(-2,-2)$ instead. But it is a huge error. Since my checkerboard patterns have been synthesized by MATLAB and I have picked $K$ on my own, I know that the original values for $f_x$, $f_y$, $p_x$ and $p_y$.

Comment: @stressedout I think the one I'm thinking of is the homography matrix version. What quantity are you talking about when you "get $\pm 5.14 ....$"? Are you talking about the coordinates of the principal point?  I don't quite understand what "worldframe is on the checkerboard" means. As long as your camera can take different pictures at different angles of the checkerboard, and it's unambiguously marked, I don't see what could impede the computation.

Comment: @rschwieb  Yes, sorry for not making it clear. $p_x = 500$ and $p_y = 750$. I get values close to these values but sometimes they're both negative and sometimes they're both positive. I think I should allow $f_x$ and $f_y$ to be negative too and they use their signs to find the correct values for the principal point?

Comment: @rschwieb I just saw your edit. You need to choose a frame of reference for your $3$ dimensional world (in homogeneous coordinates) and a frame of reference for the camera. The image plane which is $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is assumed to be attached to the camera's frame of reference. The center of the camera is where its lens is. If you choose the frame of reference of your $3$-D world on the checkerboard, (i.e. the checkerboard is situated at the x-y plane), then all points on the checkerboard have the coordinates $(x,y,0,1)^t$, giving no information about the third column of the camera matrix $P$.

Comment: Can it be that you have 2 solutions $UDV^t$ and $(-U)D(-V)^t$. One where $U$ and $V$ are both positive definite, and the other where they are both negative definite? If so, you can try them and pick the positive definite ones.